# regex - Only alphabet letters and ñ

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that allows only alphabet letters (both small and capital) and letter ñ, also small and capital. (n and Ñ) in Java. Can someone help me?

**UPDATE:** Per correction from the people commenting, I put here some of the expressions I used previously for testing. `"\\P{L}+"`, `"[a-zA-Z\u00f1\u00d1]*"` and `"[a-zA-ZñÑ]*"`. The reason for this not working if as the comments follow.

Comment: This is a really easy one. You should be able to do this in lesson 1 of any regex tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying just doing that, but seems I'm missing something because it keeps rejecting on cases like ñ and Ñ.

Comment: Can we see your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Before posting I used some regex in other posts, and tested them. But seems that the matches() function from java keeps giving false, and doesn't admit words with ñ. For example I tried the `"\\P{L}+"` regex, but it didn't seem to work, I just tried this one also `"[a-zA-ZñÑ]*"`, and the alternate version that was posted below: `"[a-zA-Z\u00f1\u00d1]*"`. All of them for some reason bounce with the same result.

Comment: First of all, my apologies for the question. Apparently all the regex didn't work, but there was some codification issue in my application which was solved with a filter in the web.xml. At first I thought it didn't work, but seems that make this filter first thing in the web.xml also affects (I make it third, or fourth filter, and didn't work, so I made it first, and work perfectly). To all those who answered and had the patience to explain my wrongs firsthand, you have my thanks =)

Answer (score 10):

This regex will work, as a string literal:

```
"[a-zA-Z\u00f1\u00d1]*"
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
"[a-zA-ZñÑ]*"
```

The `\u00f1` is the special code for lowercase ñ, and the `\u00d1` stands for uppercase Ñ. It might be possible to simply type these characters into the regex instead, but it might not work, so better safe than sorry.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working when making matches()on Java, I put the input with ñ, and it returns false. Also I find weird that it prints the word Castañeda like this: CastaÃ±eda. May Java be messing with the codification?

Comment: I don't really know much about how to make programs that don't like special characters like them anyway. Sorry.

Comment: @Xanathos Without code example which we could use to reproduce this problem we can only guess what is wrong. You should post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)